# Parameters passed from nant to a <script> method

Tags: datetime, nant

How do you pass a parameter to a  method from nant? The nant  method can take a project as parameter why not take any other type parameter?
http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/script.html

The example give in the question takes zero arguments. 
[Month name in NAnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771239/month-name-in-nant/25022654#25022654)

```
<property name="build.date" value="${datetime::parse('2014-07-29 10:21:02')}" />
<property name="build.month" value="${utils::GetMonth(${build.date})}}" /> 

[Function("GetMonth")]
public static string GetMonth(DateTime date)
{
    return date.ToLongDateString().Split(new Char[]{' '})[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the second pair of curly braces, like this:

```
<property name="build.month" value="${utils::GetMonth(build.date)}" />
```

In case there's a problem passing `DateTime`, you can try switching to `string` parameter instead and parse it the proper way in the C# code.